# Apply DataTemplate to one type only

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I am trying to apply the datatemplate only to type `Genre`. But it also gets applied to `List<string>` after `Search_Click`. How do I make the `ListBox` apply `DataTemplate` only to `Genre` data?

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="genreTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:Genre}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
        <StackPanel Margin="4">
            <TextBlock
                FontSize="20"
                Foreground="Red"
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                TextAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock
                FontSize="16"
                Text="{Binding Count}"
                TextAlignment="Right" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

 </DataTemplate>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class Genre
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public string Drive { get; set; }
}


private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = Constants.allMoviesPath;

    var ext = new List<string> { @".txt", @".ini", @".exe", @".mob", @".srt", @".ass" };

    lstBox.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + SearchString + "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Where(f => !ext.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f)))
               .Select(f => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
               .ToList();
}

private void btnStats_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     lstBox.ItemsSource = FileLists.MoviesCountSizeStats();
}
```

return type of `MoviesCountSizeStats()` is `List<Genre>`

```
<ListBox
        x:Name="lstBox"
        Background="CadetBlue"
        FontFamily="Consolas"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="DemiBold"
        ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource genreTemplate}"
        MouseDoubleClick="lstBox_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

Comment: I think removing _ItemTemplate_ attribute from <ListBox> and putting template definition into <ListBox.Resources> should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying the template to *all* items in the list box, as you are doing now, add the template as a resource to the `ListBox.Resources` (or other suitable resource dictionary), with an implicit key (i.e. implied by the `TargetType`), and let the template be selected automatically for the item type:

```xml
<ListBox
        x:Name="lstBox"
        Background="CadetBlue"
        FontFamily="Consolas"
        FontSize="14"
        FontWeight="DemiBold"
        ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}"
        MouseDoubleClick="lstBox_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Genre}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2">
                <StackPanel Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="20"
                        Foreground="Red"
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        TextAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="16"
                        Text="{Binding Count}"
                        TextAlignment="Right" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

You can add other templates as necessary for the other data types that might appear in the list box.